# общий метод для проверки открытия и сохранения файла

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли сделать какой-то общий метод?

```
 private void LoadFile()
        {
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Текст|*.txt|Код C#|*.cs";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fname = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Open); 
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs); 
                string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                fs.Close();
                textBox1.Text = text;
            }
        }
        private void SaveFile()
        {
          saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Текст|*.txt|Код C#|*.cs";
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fname = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Create); 
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
                sw.Close();
                fs.Close();
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "общим" методом и причем здесь многопоточность?

Comment: Что-то вроде проверки, что нужно сделать: сохранить, открыть, поменять шрифт и т.д.

Comment: Такое проверяется только через непосредственный тестовый запуск программы. И что значит: "...поменять шрифт"? В файле txt или cs никакой информации о шрифте не сохраняется.

Comment: Про шрифт я это имела в виду:.            private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
    fontDialog1.ShowColor = true;

    fontDialog1.Font = textBox1.Font;
    fontDialog1.Color = textBox1.ForeColor;

    if(fontDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel )
    {
       textBox1.Font = fontDialog1.Font ;
       textBox1.ForeColor = fontDialog1.Color;
    }
 }

Comment: Вы unit тест хотите сделать? Диалог с пользователем таким образом, на сколько я знаю, не тестируют. Хотя можно создать интерфейс с этими двумя методами, и для тестов использовать реализацию этого интерфейса с фейковыми ответами пользователя, но это все равно бред какой-то будет.

Comment: Нет, совершенно не это

Comment: В этих методах нет практически ничего общего: в одном `Open`, в другом `Save`, в одном `Reader`, в другом `Writer`. Так что общий метод не сделать. Разве что текст фильтра можно сделать `const` или `readonly` полем.

Comment: Нужен метод для проверки диалога

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, можно упростить ваш код до такого:

```
void LoadFile()
{
    if (RunDialog(openFileDialog1))
        textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}

void SaveFile()
{
    if (RunDialog(saveFileDialog1))
        File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, textBox1.Text);
}

bool RunDialog(System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog dlg)
{
    dlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    dlg.FileName = "";
    dlg.Filter = "Текст|*.txt|Код C#|*.cs";
    return (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK);
}
```